# Azure Signal R Service with Angular 13

Tags: c#, angular, signalr, signalr.client, azure-signalr

I've been trying to setup an integration between an Angular 13 client-side app and a .NET Framework 4.8 API with an Azure Signal R Service. After much trial and error this week I have finally got my api to build without CORS errors and I can make a successful negotiate call using postman. I am using the **@aspnet/signalr** client-side package since that is the only signal R package that support Azure Signal R Services.

Below is the angular code I am using to make a connection to my signal R hub named DashboardHub

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';

@Injectable()
export class SignalrService {
    public initializeSignalRConnection(): void {
        let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("http://localhost:58556/signalr/dashboardhub")
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
        .build();

        connection.start()
        .then(() => { 
            console.log("connection.start");
            //connection.invoke("send", "Hello")
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("connection start error", error);
        });

        connection.on("send", data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is within the **connection.start** which returns an **error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')**. Screenshot of that browser error below.

[image: Browser Connection Error]

API Signal R mapping for context
[image: SignalR API Mapping]

And here is the DashboardHub for reference
[image: DashboardHub]